# I can't use jQuery in Code pen

Tags: jquery, html

I just started learning j query and want to test it in code pen but i can't get the result i intend for.
https://codepen.io/Sunny143/pen/MrJqrM

Below is my HTML code

```
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1     /jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

Below is my j query code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseOver(function(){
    alert("mouseover the heading");
  });
});
```

Please help me on this one, Thank you so much in advance.

Edit: I changed the code in the Code pen link i given above as my question got clarified, so please don't refer that link

Comment: What are you expecting to get and what did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error in your code if you see your console. Use `mouseover` instead of `mouseOver`.
So just replace your code from:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseOver(function(){
    alert("mouseover the heading");
  });
});
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseover(function(){
    alert("mouseover the heading");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did have to change `mouseOver` to `mouseover` but jQuery works fine in Codepen as seen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXdLVJ

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1").mouseover(function(){
    alert("mouseover the heading");
  });
   });
```

Also, instead of loading libraries in `<head>` you can use the settings of your pen and add external resources.

[image: Codepen settings JS]

Comment: Oh, already answered by @Nasqash. Wish we had questions updates on editing.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use camel case.

try

```
.mouseover()
```

or try that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on('mouseover',function(){
    $("h1").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```